# Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method editArtifact on Editing Resource Name

Tags: wso2

I am trying to edit a resource name (required field) in gov. registry 4.6.0 and get the error given below. What is causing this to happen and what is the resolution? I cannot find any documentation explaining how to edit a resource without getting this error.

Thanks

```
    [2014-02-19 13:44:19,892] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.generic.ui.utils.Man
    ageGenericArtifactUtil} -  Failed to add/edit artifact details. Exception occurr
    ed while trying to invoke service method editArtifact
    org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occurred while trying to invoke service me
thod editArtifact
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.j
ava:531)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(
OutInAxisOperation.java:367)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisO
peration.java:413)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(Out
InAxisOperation.java:224)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:
149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.generic.stub.ManageGenericArtifactServiceS
tub.editArtifact(ManageGenericArtifactServiceStub.java:4000)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.generic.ui.clients.ManageGenericArtifactSe
rviceClient.editArtifact(ManageGenericArtifactServiceClient.java:109)
        at org.wso2.carbon.governance.generic.ui.utils.ManageGenericArtifactUtil
.addArtifactContent(ManageGenericArtifactUtil.java:64)
        at org.apache.jsp.generic.add_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(org.apac
he.jsp.generic.add_005fajaxprocessor_jsp:95)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper
.java:403)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:4
92)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(Con
textPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service
(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(P
roxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyS
ervlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(Delegati
onServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(Charact
erSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(C
ompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTo
mcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoa
derValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.i
nvoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:101)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(T
omcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValv
e.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.inv
oke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(Ca
rbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoin
t.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: I noticed that there is a patch that may resolve this issue. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-2033 . Ho do I apply the patch that is given as a potential resolution to this? The patch is REGISTRY-2033.patch

Answer (score 0):

As you found out, this *could be resolved* by applying the patch at https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-2033.

As I can see from the attached patch, you should apply the patch to following component:

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/governance/org.wso2.carbon.governance.api/4.2.1/

If you look at `wso2greg-4.6.0/repository/components/plugins/` you will see that it uses `org.wso2.carbon.governance.api_4.2.1.jar`

You should be able to checkout above component, apply patch and build it.

You can then copy the newly built jar as a patch to `wso2greg-4.6.0/repository/components/patches/patchXXXX/` where `XXXX` is the patch number.

It's better to rename the jar at target directory to match with the jar name in plugins.

i.e. `org.wso2.carbon.governance.api-4.2.1.jar` -> `org.wso2.carbon.governance.api_4.2.1.jar`

When you restart the server, the patch will be applied. You may check `md5sum` of the jar inside plugins to make sure the patch is applied correctly.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have no idea how to compile and build a jar file. I am just using the repository to show a demo to my management tomorrow morning. Is this something that can be done and the jar attached in this thread so I can copy and place it in the correct location?

Comment: I read some docs to try to build what you said I get more than 100 errors which refer to not existent packages starting at GovernanceArtifactManager.java:21: error: package org.apache.axiom.om does not exist
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory;  I tried to build the java file but probably need a lot more. Any quick help would be much appreciated

Comment: Hi Cari, I think you will have to build the platform components to avoid the error. Let me check on the error and get back to you.

Comment: Hi, I attached the patched jar to the JIRA. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-2033. Please follow instructions mentioned in my answer. Thanks!